# Millisec. in filename with C

Tags: c

I find no indication that there is a format for milliseconds in C.
I save images more than once a second and need an additional index.
My code now is:

```
time_t     now;
struct tm  ts;
time(&now);
ts = *localtime(&now);
strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y%m%d-%H%M%S", &ts);
```

Linux 4.9.59-v7+ #1047 SMP Sun Oct 29 12:19:23 GMT 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
GNU Make 4.1

Comment: See `gettimeofday()` and `clock_gettime()`

Comment: Another potential solution (perhaps you thought of this but decided against it) is to simply append an additional digit on images that were saved at the same exact time (-1,-2,-3, etc).  I think the end result would be more human-readable than simply milliseconds.

Comment: +1 for @arcsin’s solution, especially since milliseconds are often not enough to distinguish different files...

Comment: @arcsin’s so I do it at the moment, but the reset at the end of seconds is complicated, or is there a one-liner?

Comment: @arcsin’s my frame reset code is    if (buf[14] != bufold[14])
        {
        frame = 0;
        size_t destination_size = sizeof (bufold);
        strncpy(bufold, buf, destination_size);
        }